# Download Artifact from other pipeline in Multistage YAML

Tags: azure-devops

In azure devops i am trying to create a multistage release definition via yaml. Build is done via classic editor and the artifacts are uploaded to azure pipelines. so i want to access a specific artifact for deployment

`- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 displayName: 'Download Pipeline Artifact' inputs: buildType: specific project: 'vvxxxxxx-vxxv-xxxv-vxxx-xxxxxxvvxxvv' definition: 5 buildVersionToDownload: specific pipelineId: 'SSE_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_Auto-import_dev_20200423.4' artifactName: Service targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'`

When i try it via classic release using task 'Download Pipeline Artifact' it's successful but when I try it via yaml it's failing with error *"##[error]Run Id is not valid: SSE_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_Auto-import_dev_20200423.4"*
if there is anyother way to get the artifact from a pipeline would be helpful and also instead of hardcoding pipelineId I want to make it dynamic as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Download Artifact from other pipeline in Multistage YAML

The value of the `pipelineId` should be the ID of the build pipeline, which  you want to download, rather than the name/title of the build pipeline.

Find the build pipeline you want to download, click on a build record you want to download, you could see it in the web address bar of the browser:

[image]

> also instead of hardcoding pipelineId I want to make it dynamic as
>   well.

If you don't want hard code the `pipelineId/runid` in YAML definition, you can consider to pass queue variable as a work around.

For example:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    source: 'specific'
    artifact: 'drop'
    path: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/bin
    project: 'AndroidBuild'
    pipeline: 12
    runVersion: 'specific'
    runId: $(buildid)
```

In above definition, `buildid` is the variable, and you can configure its value at queue time:

[image]

This do not need you to do any modification to the pipeline when you want to choosing another runId, just pass the value at queue time.

Hope this helps.